# Why GIL lock is needed when calling python function in C extension?

Tags: python, c

I am writing C Extension for python in which I am calling Python function as callback. Can anyone explain what's the need for GIL here? As far as I know, GIL is needed to make sure only one thread to access to native functions at a time. But here we are calling python function from C (I am sorry If it's basic question)

```
void hsio_callback(int value){
if(py_callback != NULL){
    PyObject *arg, *result;
    arg = Py_BuildValue("(i)", value);

    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    result = PyEval_CallObject(py_callback, arg);

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    if(result == NULL)
        printf("Error\n");
    Py_DECREF(result);
}
```

}

Comment: Actually the GIL does by default pretty much the opposite of what you think. Calling a "native" C function is one of the scenarios where it can get released. While actively working through Python code it is usually active.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. I will explore further.